# Applying to same school for a different grad program

Tags: graduate-admissions

I applied to school A for law school and got rejected. Now I'm planning to reapply but for a different grad program. Will the school have all my records from the law school?

Comment: It would probably help to clarify what you _really_ want to know. As it is, I can't imagine any reason why this would matter except that you expect the two applications to show inconsistent information and are wondering if they will catch you, which I hope is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Only they can say. But even if they do it should have no affect on your chances. People can be better prepared for some things than for others. People can have a better record in some things than in others. Programs can be more or less competitive than others.

Unless you ask, just assume they do. But rules will probably make it hard/impossible for them to use things beyond what is in your application for that individual program (US view).

Answer (score 0):

If by Rejected you mean that you did not get into Laws, they will not have any records besides that you were a student who try to get into the Laws program, meaning they will have your basic information and maybe an aspirant number in their database.

However, if by Rejected, you mean that you were in Laws and then get kick out of the program, then yes, they will have record of your grades.